# Django 2.2.2: "Manager isn't accessible via (Model) instances" on Admin

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.7

**Hello SO,**

I just created two models:

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
from uuid_upload_path import upload_to
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class StorageObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # types
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.URLField(blank=True)

    @cached_property
    def file_type(self):
        if self.file:
            return 1
        elif self.image:
            return 2
        elif self.link:
            return 3

    def clean(self):
        if self.file and (self.image or self.link):
            raise ValidationError(_('Storage Objects can only contain one storage type each'))
        elif self.image and (self.link or self.file):
            raise ValidationError(_('Storage Objects can only contain one storage type each'))
        elif self.link and (self.file or self.image):
            raise ValidationError(_('Storage Objects can only contain one storage type each'))
        if not (self.link or self.image or self.file):
            raise ValidationError(_('Storage Objects must contain exactly one storage type'))

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (by %s)' % (self.name, self.owner)


class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = models.ManyToManyField(StorageObject)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As the title says I´m getting an `AttributeError` whenever I am trying to create a `Collection` via admin-interface.
However creating the `StorageObject` works perfectly fine and gets propperly cleaned.

I googled about this message, and most people seem to have forgotten the instance brackets (like StorageObject() ) somewhere. Maybe I am blind, but I just can´ t find the mistake.

So I went on and deleted my custom function `file_type` and `clean`, but still the same result.

What am I missing here? Thanks for your time!

**Stack**

```
 File "C:\Users\[..]\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 176, in __get__
        raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)
    AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Collection instances
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add a field `objects` on your models, this is conflicting with the model `Manager` that's also called `objects`. `Collection.objects` should return a `Manager` unless you decide to give it a different name (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/)).

Comment: Holy smokes. It seems pretty obvious as soon as one knows it. Thank you very much sir. I will check back as soon as I can verify the answer and accept it as the solution!

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you very much again!